# Configuring and managing opentrust

Tags: appexchange

I want to work with opentrust for the electronic signature, Is there anyone have a demo about configuring and working with application?!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I work for OpenTrust, but not in the Digital Signature business. 
first download the app on the AppExchange

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3HFdEAN&tab=g

Then go to https://www.opentrust.com/en/information-request?pid=327

and request a test account for testing the OpenTrust Protect&Sign App for SalesForce.

Hope this helps.

Fred